# Markov Chain transition matrix

Tags: python, matrix, probability, hidden-markov-models, markov-chains

I am looking for a way to compute a Markov transition matrix from a customer transactions list of an ecommerce website.

Basically I would need a nxn matrix with n as the number of purchased products, and in each row there would be the probability of let's say, purchasing product 1 , I have X probability of purchasing product 2, y probability of purchasing product 1 again, and so on. We can assume the initial state to be an array with a 1 on product 1 and a 0 for all the other products (we just bought product 1 for now).

Is there some sort of python package able to compute the transition matrix probabilities for me feeding the purchase data? In all the examples I looked at people were just feeding a pre computed matrix.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you can use `markovchain` package. You can find more details about this package [here](https://github.com/dead-beef/markovchain).You can install it using `pip install markovchain` and then compute the transition matrix by training a text base Markov model. For example:

```
from markovchain.text import MarkovText, ReplyMode

markov = MarkovText()

with open('data.txt') as fp:
    markov.data(fp.read())

with open('data2.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        markov.data(line, part=True)
markov.data('', part=False)

print(markov())
print(markov(max_length=16, reply_to='sentence start', reply_mode=ReplyMode.END))

markov.save('markov.json')

markov = MarkovText.from_file('markov.json')
```